# Fastest way to upload or download lat long to server

Tags: android, mysql

I am in need to upload and download 3 fields containing latitude,longitude and last seen from mysql-php filtered by email. What is the fastest as well as less memory consuming method to do so from Android ?

Tried Async in background but takes around 10sec to return.

public class LocationWebService extends AsyncTask {

```
public LocationWebService() {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

@Override
protected Boolean doInBackground(String... arg0) {
    String lat = arg0[0];
    String lng = arg0[1];
    String url = arg0[2];
    String email = arg0[3];
    Log.e("LAT",arg0[0]);
    Log.e("LNG",arg0[1]);
    Log.e("URL",arg0[2]);
    Log.e("EMAIL",arg0[3]);
    InputStream is = null;
    List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("latitude", lat));
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("longitude", lng));
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("email", email));
    String result = null;

    try{
        HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
        httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
        HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
        is = entity.getContent();

        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, "UTF-8"), 8);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        String line = null;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
        {
            sb.append(line + "\n");
        }
        result = sb.toString();
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

}

Comment: please add what u tried?

Comment: dont user HtttpClient. its deprecated. try Retrofit or Volley libraries. google it

Answer (score 0):

I don't think your code above will cost so long time as 10 seconds unless there is something wrong with your network or your server.